# How to display the string values of a table refering to Two foreign ID keys on the main table

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

So I have this database

**TABLE: rates**

```
ID  |  FID  |  TID  |  RATE
---------------------------
 1  |   1   |   2   |  0.3
 2  |   1   |   3   |  1.2
 3  |   1   |   4   |  4.5
 4  |   2   |   1   |  1.3
 5  |   2   |   3   |  3.3
 6  |   2   |   4   |  4.4
```

**TABLE: currencies**

```
ID  |   Name   |  Symbol
---------------------
 1  |   Euro   |   E   
 2  |   Pound  |   P   
 3  |  Dollar  |   $   
 4  |   CAD    |   C
```

So what I tried so far was

```
SELECT  rates.*,
    currencies.name,
    currencies.symbol FROM RATES 
JOIN CURRENCIES ON
(rates.fid = currencies.id)
```

Which worked but only for 1 column. I could not find a way to add more. Also I want to give a custom output name  for each currency. So the final output should be:

```
ID | FromCurrency (FID) | ToCurrency (TID) | Rate
```

Comment: So you need to name of the currencies like `FromCurrency -> Euro` `ToCurrency->Dollar` ?

Comment: Yes. Just the ids of the foreigh tables beautifully displayed as the name that is equal to the id from the rates table.

Comment: SELECT  rates.id, 
    currencies.name as fromCurrency,
    currencies.name as toCurrency, 
    rates.rate
FROM RATES 
JOIN CURRENCIES ON
(rates.fid = currencies.id)

It should be something like this though I am missing something. This is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do multiple joins, and as you are using the same table for both joins, give them an alias.

Something like this:

```
SELECT  rates.ID,
    a.name AS 'FromCurrency (FID)',
    a.symbol AS 'FID Symbol',
    b.name AS 'ToCurrency (TID)',
    b.symbol AS 'TID Symbol',
    rates.rate
FROM RATES 
JOIN CURRENCIES AS a ON
(rates.fid = a.id)
JOIN CURRENCIES AS b ON
(rates.tid = b.id)
```

[Here is a working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac99d/2)

Comment: Worked like a dream. Thanks. The "AS" command was something I was missing. The final SQL code is:
SELECT  rates.id, 
    fc.name as fromCurrency,
    tc.name as toCurrency, 
    rates.rate
FROM RATES 
JOIN CURRENCIES as fc ON
(rates.fid = fc.id)
JOIN CURRENCIES as tc ON
(rates.tid = tc.id)